# How do i get the coordinates of vertices of shapes instead of the CORNERS coordinates in fabric js?

Tags: html, canvas, fabricjs

I tried the following code but it gives coordinates of control corner not of the vertices, I WANT POINTS?

```
<!--fabric js function to get coordinates of active object-->
    function getCoords(oCoords) {
        return {
          tl: new fabric.Point(oCoords.tl.x, oCoords.tl.y),
          tr: new fabric.Point(oCoords.tr.x, oCoords.tr.y),
          bl: new fabric.Point(oCoords.bl.x, oCoords.bl.y),
          br: new fabric.Point(oCoords.br.x, oCoords.br.y)
        }
      }
```

Comment: fabric and fabricjs arn't the same thing. Fabric is a python module

Comment: no its not the same

Comment: @ManjunathBiradar. Please do not post duplicate questions...just wait for someone to answer. ;-)